# How to Integrate Bootstrap Template with MVC

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, templates, model-view-controller, themes

I have downloaded a Bootstrap template(Complete GUI) from the internet and I want to add functionality to the same template using MVC. So how should I add that template to my MVC project. 
I have seen many tutorials but they only tell you how to add a theme not an entire template.

I am using the cardio theme: http://tympanus.net/Freebies/Cardio/

Answer (score 0):

The default MVC project includes a _Layout.cshtml file, which contains the main HTML for your template. Replace that with the HTML in the template you downloaded, making sure to copy the bits of Razor from the old code.

Then you'll need to replace the CSS files with the ones from the downloaded template and it should all work.

This all depends on how well written the template is, but I've done this many times with no problem.